# We're sorry, but something went wrong. (Rails, Nginx, Puma, Postgres, Capistrano)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, nginx

So I have been trying to deploy my rails app with no luck. There is no problem when I run:

> cap production deploy

but when I open my server ip, the only thing I see is:

### We're sorry, but something went wrong.

### If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

And I have checked the production.log the output is:

```
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:incall' railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in call'
puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:78:incall' puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/server.rb:541:in handle_request'
puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/server.rb:388:inprocess_client' puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/server.rb:270:in block in run'
puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:incall' puma (2.14.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in block in spawn_thread'
```

Files:

[Nginx.conf](http://pastie.org/10533731)

[production.rb](http://pastie.org/10533737)

How do I fix this? What could be the problem, any ideas?

Comment: you should post full stacktrace.

Comment: nginx config would also be nice. And the information on how you integrate puma with calistrano (i suppose it's `capistrano-puma` gem)

Comment: I don't know how to do a full stacktrace :(

Yes, that's how i integrated puma. Gemfile: http://pastie.org/10533739